# Editor placeholder in source file swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

[This happened to me please help me please,Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHxFR.png)

The code here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuCollectionViewCell", for: IndexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

---

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHxFR.png)
View image by clicking "This happened to me please help me please. Thank you."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to write it like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I edit it like you but it still got error

Comment: not IndexPath. indexPath

Comment: Thank you a lot !